# Alternative to Atmel programmers

Tags: atmel, programmer

I am currently using the Dragon AVR to program ATMEGA88 chips on board using ISP I/F. My problem is that it seems somewhat flakey. Is there a reasonably cheap non-Atmel alternative? Ideally a more universal machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you are asking for something "universal" and non-atmel, which I think doesn't exist, but I suggest the avrisp MKII, is cheaper and very reliable: [avrisp MKII](http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500054#tc:description)

Comment: Thanks - you get an upvote! However, I have one of those and it also will not work. I think the problem is some combination of Studio version, USB drivers and firmware. Ideally I want something that does not rely on Studio to drive it

Comment: Have you tried the avrdude software with your existing programmers?

Comment: Note that the avrispMKII is no longer being manufactured.

Comment: Seems the winning combo is AVR Dragon with downgraded firmware combined with Studio 4 (downgraded from 6). Any other more modern combination does not seem to work. A total PITA - I will be avoiding designing with Atmel in future.